# How to cross reference input method in docstring?

Tags: documentation

I'd like to cross reference an input method from a minor mode docstring:

```
(define-derived-mode xxx
  ...
  "Super `xxx' derived mode.

  Cool to use with input method `my-magic-input-method'.")
```

Now `my-magic-input-method` is not linked in `*Help*` window. Is there a way to inform Emacs about input method links like there are methods to inform it about variables, functions and symbols?

Comment: This is the function responsible for parsing doc-strings: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0537943561a37b54467bec19d1b8afbeba8e1e58/src/doc.c#L681 - it doesn't seem like it has anything special for input modes though. Sounds like a good subject for a feature request though. It would be nice to be able to link to the help page of input method from a function help page.